# Unable to send file to Telegram Channel

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telethon

Error below:

```
Failed to convert James Blake - Never Dreamed.mp4 to media. Not an existing file, an HTTP URL or a valid bot-API-like file ID
```

Function that I am running is here.

```
async def gramain():
    # Getting information about yourself
    me = await bott.get_me()
    print(me.stringify())
    filesww = os.listdir('media').pop()
    now = os.getcwd()
    mediadir = now + "/media/"
    vid = open(mediadir+filesww, 'r')
    # await bot.send_message(chat, 'Hello, friend!')
    await bott.send_file(chat, filesww, video_note=True)
```

I trying to use this function from the library Telethon.
https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/client.html#telethon.client.uploads.UploadMethods.send_file

I am unable to find out what the issue is. Please help!

Comment: Make sure the file path exists in disk.

Comment: file path exists. Can I check anyway that file exists? But it says cannot convert to ... media.

Comment: The error clearly indicates "Not an existing file". You can use [`os.path.exists`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.exists) to make sure the file does exist. Most likely the working directory is just not what you expect.